# Webpack hmr: __webpack_hmr 404 not found

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm using webpack-dev-server for hot module replacement. It's working just fine, but this error keeps showing up in the console every couple of seconds: `GET http://mysite:8080/__webpack_hmr 404 (Not Found)`.

Here's my webpack.config.js:

```js
var webpack = require('webpack'),
  hostname = 'mysite',
  port = 8080;

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './src/js/main.js',
    './dev/requireCss.js',
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    // I'm assuming the fault lies in the following line, but I can't figure out what's wrong
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://' +
      hostname +
      ':' +
      port +
      '/__webpack_hmr',
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/webpack',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: 'http://' + hostname + ':' + port + '/',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader?presets[]=react&presets[]=es2015'],
      }, // removed some loaders for brevity
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.json', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: __dirname + '/dev',
    hot: true,
    proxy: [
      {
        path: /\/(?!__webpack_hmr).+/, // I get the same error if I change this to 'path: /\/.+/'
        target: 'http://my-backend.localhost',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

The idea is that the dev-server should forward all requests except from `/` and `__webpack_hmr` to my backend (`my-backend.localhost`). This works fine for everything except `__webpack_hmr`.

Is there something I can change in my conf to make the error disappear?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Fixed by deleting the following line under *entry*:
`'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://'+hostname+':'+port+'/__webpack_hmr'`. <s>I don't know why it worked.</s> See Amin Ariana's answer for an explanation to why this may work for you.

Comment: I honestly don't even know why I had a similar line like that in my config file, but it worked for me too. Must have been something I had seen when looking at other projects during setup. Deleted the line, lost the error, no performance issues. Good shot, Hansn.

Comment: I think that has to do with hot reloading and should only be used in the dev enviroment.

Comment: I have no such thing in my entry and still get this error :(

Comment: @EdmundReed Do you still have the issue? I have the same problem as you.

Comment: @AdrianMoisa my issue was that I mistakenly thought running `webpack-dev-server` wrote the bundle to disk, since it doesn't my `webpack-dev-server` was using old files which were bundled with the above entry that should be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, it seems that this is not my issue.

Answer (score 23):

This line in entry array does not play well with `webpack-dev-server`:

```
webpack-hot-middleware/client
```

because it's a requirement of `webpack-hot-middleware` for working with any server other than `webpack-dev-server` (such as `express` or some such).

I ran into this mixed-server issue by following Webpack tutorials. They should update it so that the entry point for the config file of Webpack using webpack-dev-server doesn't require an artifact produced by webpack-hot-middleware, which tries to hot-emit the developer's module updates into a custom-built server depending on it.

You can remove that line from the entry array, which in case of using dev-server should solve the problem.

FYI That line in your code came from here:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-hot-middleware
where it says:

> Add `webpack-hot-middleware/client?...` into the
>   [webpack config's] entry array. This connects to the server to receive
>   notifications when the bundle rebuilds and then updates your client
>   bundle accordingly.

Based on your question, "I'm using webpack-dev-server", you're therefore not using "webpack-hot-middleware" and should remove the entry line.

Answer (score 4):

I will add here my answer because in my case that was the cause of this issue.

Assuming you are using *Next.JS*.

After receiving this issue, all I had to do is to close the debug window of the nodeJS (chrome debugging tool, but for the BE, not the UI) and then just to start the project again using `npm start`

I hope it will help anyone that face it (the other answers here didn't suit me)

Answer (score 0):

after changing the port number issue got resolved